# MongoDB Atlas - mongodump local/oplog.rs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodump

Im trying to mongodump local/oplog.rs but the console return error

This is my command

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://acc:pass@cluster0-pdpwa.mongodb.net/local" -c oplog.rs -o ./local_oplog
```

User role: dbAdmin > local

```
Failed: error getting collection options: error running `listCollections`. Database: `local` Err: user is not allowed to do action [listCollections] on [local.]
```

User role: readWriteAnyDatabase

```
Failed: error dumping metadata: error running `listIndexes`. Collection: `local.oplog.rs` Err: not authorized on local to execute command { listIndexes: "oplog.rs", cursor: {  } }
```

Comment: What is your Atlas instance type?